# Cannot login into openfire account via XMPP

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I have a very simple Java application that sends messages to an openfire server using a custom account called "thesis.dimfccs.sensors", who is seding a message to another custom account called "thesis.dimfccs".

I am using openfire 3.9.1 and my Java application is able to connect to the server, but it is unable to login into it. When I try to login, I get the following error:

```
Initializing connection to server localhost, port 5222, service gmail.com
Connected: true
Logging in: thesis.dimfccs.sensors, thesis.dimfccs.sensors.pwd
Exception in thread "main" No response from the server.: 
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:73)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:357)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:243)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:366)
    at javacodegeeks.XmppManager.performLogin(XmppManager.java:76)
    at javacodegeeks.XmppLocalTest.main(XmppLocalTest.java:44)
```

I know that the password and name for the test account are correct because I can enter the Spark IM client using them.

However, what **really blows my mind**, is that if I do the exact same thing using the "admin" account, everything works!

I have double checked the thesis.dimfccs.sensors password and gave it admin access, but it is still not enough.

Here is the code:

**Main.java:**

```
public class XmppLocalTest {

    //Total number of messages sent during one minute.
    public static final int MESSAGES_NUMBER = 120;

    //Each message will have a random number between 0 and MAX_RANDOM.
    public static final int MAX_RANDOM = 100;

    private static final String SENDER_USERNAME = "thesis.dimfccs.sensors";
    private static final String SENDER_PASSWORD = "thesis.dimfccs.sensors.pwd";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String username = SENDER_USERNAME;
        String password = SENDER_PASSWORD;
        XmppManager xmppManager = new XmppManager("localhost", 5222,
                "gmail.com");

        xmppManager.init();

        xmppManager.performLogin(username, password);
        System.out.println("Login performed with success, setting status.");
        xmppManager.setStatus(true, "Let the pain begin!");

        System.out.println("Setting up receivers");
        xmppManager.createEntry("thesis.dimfccs", "thesis.dimfccs");

        //go message!
        xmppManager.sendMessage("Hello world!", "thesis.dimfccs@gmail.com");

        xmppManager.destroy();
    }
}
```

**XmppManager.java:**

```
package javacodegeeks;

/**
 * Main class with all the logic of the connection. Followed from the tutorials:
 * http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/xmpp-im-with-smack-for-java.html
 * */

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence.Type;

public class XmppManager {

    private static final int packetReplyTimeout = 500; // millis

    private String server;
    private int port;
    private String service;

    private ConnectionConfiguration config;
    private XMPPConnection connection;

    private ChatManager chatManager;
    private MessageListener messageListener;

    public XmppManager(String aServer, int aPort, String aService) {
        server = aServer;
        port = aPort;
        service = aService;
    }

    public XmppManager(String server, int port) {
        this(server, port, null);
    }

    public void init() throws XMPPException {

        System.out.println(String.format("Initializing connection to server " +  server + ", port " + port
                + ", service " + service));

        SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(packetReplyTimeout);

        if(service != null)
            config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port, service);
        else
            config = new ConnectionConfiguration(server, port);

//      config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
//      config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.disabled);
//      SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
        config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);

        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();

        System.out.println("Connected: " + connection.isConnected());

        chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
        messageListener = new MyMessageListener();

    }

    public void performLogin(String username, String password) throws XMPPException {

        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Logging in: " + username + ", " + password);
            connection.login(username, password);
        }
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean available, String status) {

        Presence.Type type = available? Type.available: Type.unavailable;
        Presence presence = new Presence(type);

        presence.setStatus(status);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);

    }

    public void destroy() {
        if (connection!=null && connection.isConnected()) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message, String buddyJID) throws XMPPException {
        System.out.println(String.format("Sending message " + message + " to user " + buddyJID));
        Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(buddyJID, messageListener);
        chat.sendMessage(message);
    }

    public void createEntry(String user, String name) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(String.format("Creating entry for buddy " + user + " with name " + name));
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        roster.createEntry(user, name, null);
    }

    private class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
            String from = message.getFrom();
            String body = message.getBody();
            System.out.println(String.format("Received message " + body + " from " + from));
        }

    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

---

NOTE: If you believe this question is poor, please leave a comment and suggest an edit instead of down-voting it. This way I can actually improve the question and everyone gets happy!

Comment: 1) Why you use `gmail.com` as serviceName? "Service name" is what you have in your openfire server settings. Or you really set up `gmail.com` there? 2) enable SASL authentication 3) don't use 'localhost' as the `host` entry, if you want to connect from different machine

Comment: 1) Because I am really used to type it xD Yes, I set it to gmail. But dont worry, I will change that in the future. 2) that is a whole new level of hell. 3) this is running in the same machine as the server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my server seemed to be inconsistent somehow. After deleting and re.creating the users, the problem got fixed !